How can I preview the result of Texture Node Editor
I'm trying to use Texture Node Editor creating brushes' texture. But I can't preview the result, it's black either in brush's settings or Texture Property. Although it works well when I use the brush painting.
How can I preview the composition result? Or is there any good practice of how to use Texture Node Editor?


Hello ! AFAIK the texture node editor is pretty much deprecated and hasn't received any significant update in years. I am actually surprised it still kind of works in latest versions.

What a pity... I think Texture Node Editor has potential to become Blender Embedded PS. Furthermore to become Blender's Substance Painter..

I believe the goal is to tie everything using a system similar to geometry nodes, with procedural textures and brush assets. But it's part of a larger rework of Blender called Everything Nodes that is several years in the works and no ETA for that particular part of Blender I'm afraid.
